# How to insert text in SmartMessageBox of smartnotification.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, messagebox

I am trying to use the SmartMessageBox functionality of the smartnotification plugin. First of all I couldn't find much documentation about it so if you have any reference link it to me please. Secondly, what I am trying to do is having a pop-up message box (provided by the SmartMessageBox functionality) but where I can insert a message that afterwards I will use somewhere else in the code. So far I have seen only examples where the SmartMessageBox "shows" something and gives the chance to click buttons, but nothing related the possibility to insert text. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

here's an example:

```
$.SmartMessageBox({
    title: title,
    content: content,
    buttons: '[no][yes]'
}, function (ButtonPressed) {
    if (ButtonPressed === "yes") {
        if(ifYes != null && ifYes != undefined)
            ifYes();
    }
    if (ButtonPressed === "no") {
        if (ifNo != null && ifNo != undefined)
            ifNo();
    }
});
```